# Latex Beamer with Polyglossia: uncover problem

Tags: beamer, xetex, polyglossia

I want to construct a fancy Arabic presentation by using polyglossia along with beamer. However, I encounter the following problem: When using the command `\uncover` or `visible` or even `invisible`, the last line of the paragraph is always visible regardless to frame numbering.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}
\usetheme{default}
% for RTL liste
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\justifying\rightskip\leftm}
\newcommand{\leftm}{\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rightskip\rightmargin

\begin{frame}{مثال حي}
بغض النظر عن سعي القائمين على المشروع للربح، إعادة تدوير النفايات الورقية لها فوائد جمة على الصعيد البيئي والاقتصادي. وفقا لإحصائيات تمت في دول العالم الأول، إعادة 
تدوير النفايات الورقية توفر 30\% من استهلاك مصانع الورق للكهرباء. 
كما أنها تساهم في حماية الغابات من القطع الجائر للأشجار لاستخدام لحاءها في صناعة الورق.

\invisible<2>{بغض النظر عن سعي القائمين على المشروع للربح، إعادة تدوير 
النفايات الورقية لها فوائد جمة على الصعيد البيئي والاقتصادي. وفقا 
لإحصائيات تمت في دول العالم الأول، إعادة 
تدوير النفايات الورقية توفر 30\% من استهلاك مصانع الورق للكهرباء. 
كما أنها تساهم في حماية الغابات من القطع الجائر للأشجار لاستخدام لحاءها 
في صناعة الورق.
}

\only<3->{جملة ما}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is the last line of the second line which is supposed to be invisible is always visible

[image]

### Update #1

This problem applies to inline texts too

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}


\usetheme{default}
% for RTL liste
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\justifying\rightskip\leftm}
\newcommand{\leftm}{\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rightskip\rightmargin

\begin{frame}{مثال حي}
بعض العبارات تذهب \invisible<2>{وتختفي مثل تلك}، تمامًا
كالطائر الذي يهاجر ثم يعود لوطنه بعد موسم. ولكن أكثر الأشياء قيمة لدى الإنسان  لا عودة %some words of this line uncovers instead of the later besides the last two words.
\uncover<3>{أما أنا مع اعترافي بتلك الحقيقة، فلا أستطيع تقبلها وتجاوزها. حتى أنني أهرب إلى الواقع وأتوهم بامتلاكها.} يا لقساوة الحياة
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `\par` before the closing brace:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1,]{Amiri}
\usetheme{default}
% for RTL liste
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\justifying\rightskip\leftm}
\newcommand{\leftm}{\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\rightskip\rightmargin

\begin{frame}{مثال حي}
بغض النظر عن سعي القائمين على المشروع للربح، إعادة تدوير النفايات الورقية لها فوائد جمة على الصعيد البيئي والاقتصادي. وفقا لإحصائيات تمت في دول العالم الأول، إعادة
تدوير النفايات الورقية توفر 30\% من استهلاك مصانع الورق للكهرباء.
كما أنها تساهم في حماية الغابات من القطع الجائر للأشجار لاستخدام لحاءها في صناعة الورق.

\invisible<2>{بغض النظر عن سعي القائمين على المشروع للربح، إعادة تدوير
النفايات الورقية لها فوائد جمة على الصعيد البيئي والاقتصادي. وفقا
لإحصائيات تمت في دول العالم الأول، إعادة
تدوير النفايات الورقية توفر 30\% من استهلاك مصانع الورق للكهرباء.
كما أنها تساهم في حماية الغابات من القطع الجائر للأشجار لاستخدام لحاءها
في صناعة الورق.\par %<---
}

\only<3->{جملة ما}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution for a whole paragraph. However, there is still a problem with inline texts. (I am gonna update my question for that)

Comment: Don't change the question ask a new one. It is a pain if an answer gets invalid because someone edited the question.